# WPML plugin translation

Tags: wordpress

This question's quite stupid, but I'm having trouble getting wpml to translate my plugin. Every translatable string is surrounded by __() calls and they appear POedit, I added translation for a couple of strings and they don't appear.

Translation for the theme is working OK.

I'm sure I'm missing something very stupid like a filename somewhere, or some function call, or something, I've read every piece of documentation I've found and I think it's confused me more. I read that you need to call setlocale, but I'm guessing wpml does that.. what might I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the second parameter in the __() calls, the textdomain name.

Comment: how do I close this question?

Answer (score 0):

Is the plugin loading the .mo file?
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_plugin_textdomain

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check this FAQ page to see different reasons for String Translation not being applied:
http://wpml.org/faq/language-setup/